# Angular momentum - Equation of Motion for 2D rigid dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

So I'm doing my best to define Equations of Motion for my 2D model of a rocket (plain cylinder). And I am stuck at the equation for deriving differential equation of the angular acceleration. I'm following the path of eventually using the Transport or Euler's theorem about inertial differentiation as follows.
[image]

But where I get stuck is how to proceed further, since all the motion occurs in 2D plane. I don't really know what to do with the cross product. Meanwhile, I've removed that part in my SIMULINK model, but I'm not entirely sure that's what I am supposed to do and the reason behind it.

If there would be someone willing to explain to me how to continue with this analysis, I would be tremendously grateful as this has already bothered me for several weeks.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: the general momentum of inertia in 3D is a tensor, so you can't really divide by it. However, in flat motion, only component $J_{zz}$ matters, so it indeed works as scalar*

If the motion is limited to 2D, then $\pmb \omega=(0,0,\omega)^\intercal$ and $\mathbf J\pmb\omega = (0,0,J_{zz}\omega)$, which means that $\pmb\omega\times\mathbf J\pmb\omega=0$. Thus in 2D ODE for rotation of rigid body is fully analogous to ODE for motion:
$$
J\dot\omega = M,\quad\text{compare to}\qquad m\dot v=F
$$

Comment: Thank you! Now I feel stupid I haven't though about it this way.